# Why space telescopes images show diffraction spikes around stars, but not galaxies?

Tags: diffraction, stars, space, telescopes

I've seen this tweet recently:
https://twitter.com/ThePlanetaryGuy/status/1544801752893067265

Additionally to the image, where it's pretty clear, the post says:

> Stars are six-pointed; everything else is a galaxy.

What makes the spikes (I assume diffraction spikes) appears only for stars? How is the light from stars different from the light from galaxies?

Answer (score 2):

The diffraction spikes are there, but they aren't as visible when the source of the light is spread out. The width of the spike is the width of the image of the object. An unresolved star makes a narrow, conspicuous spike, while for a galaxy the spike is spread out and harder to see.

Comment: If that were the only reason, should we not expect a constant ratio between the brightness of the source and the brightness of the spike? Yet the galaxies are a bit less bright than the stars, but their spikes seems very much less bright than the stars' spikes

Comment: Does it mean the stars are actually very very much saturated on the telescope sensors? Like orders of magnitude saturated ?

Comment: @Jeffrey that's due to the way we process relative brightnesses post-retina

Comment: @Jeffrey If you added up all the intensity in the pixels containing the spikes, you'd get your constant ratio, but the spikes cover more pixels.

Comment: @Jeffry Note that you cannot judge intensity of objects in published images with your eyes. For making nice display images from TESS I like to scale the data logarithmically. Others use different "stretches", but linear scaling doesn't show the details well.

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11915/what-visual-artifacts-are-expected-from-the-jwst#